# phpunit loading config file does not return anything

Tags: php, phpunit

When I try to load my config file nothing gets returned and if I don't try load it my test fails because it is trying to access a variable defined in the config file.

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap config/config.php src/Notification.php tests/NotificationTest -v --debug
```

Without config

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap  src/Notification.php tests/NotificationTest -v --debug          PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.17


Starting test 'NotificationTest::testEmail'.
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 26 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) NotificationTest::testEmail
Trying to get property of non-object

src/Notification.php:13
tests/NotificationTest.php:10

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

**UPDATE**

still errors looking for a variable in config file that i need to load

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/NotificationTest -v --debug
PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.17


Starting test 'NotificationTest::testEmail'.
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 26 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) NotificationTest::testEmail
Trying to get property of non-object

src/Notification.php:13
tests/NotificationTest.php:10

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

**UPDATE 2 - new error**

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap config/config.php tests/NotificationTest -v --debug
PHPUnit 6.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.17


Starting test 'NotificationTest::testEmail'.
INFO -  Message sent
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 128 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) NotificationTest::testEmail
TypeError: Return value of CCP\Notification::sendEmail() must be an instance of boolean, boolean returned

src/Notification.php:32
tests/NotificationTest.php:11

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

It looks like a problem with strict types and php7, something im not doing right.

source code

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace CCP;

use CCP\MyMailer;

class Notification{

    private $log;

    public function __construct(){
        global $CFG;
        $this->log = $CFG->log;
    }

    public function sendEmail(string $from, array $to, string $subject, string $body): \boolean{
        $mail = new MyMailer;
                $mail->setFrom($from);
                foreach($to as $value){
                        $mail->addAddress($value);
                }
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->Body =  $body;
        if(!$mail->send())  {
            $this->log->error(" Message could not be sent for ");
            $this->log->error(" Mailer error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
            return false;
        }  else   {
            $this->log->info(" Message sent ");
        }

        return true;
        }

    public function emailTest(){
        $mail_from = "m.w@mail.com"; # for testing
        # code to retrieve the submitter of the subnet
        $rcpt_to = ["s.u@mail.com"];
        $subject = "CCP :: IAM :: Subnet Request Approved";
        $data = "subnet was been approved by the IP Admin";
        $this->sendEmail($mail_from, $rcpt_to, $subject, $data);
    }

}
?>
```

fixed, it was bool not boolean

Comment: Have you tried running it without the --bootstrap setting at all?

Comment: it returns nothing `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit src/Notification.php tests/NotificationTest -v --debug
`. Is there specifics to creating this bootstrap file or can it be coded anyhow

Comment: Sorry - you should remove the src/Notification.php as well. Simply have the name of the tests you want it to run.

Comment: @Nigel see update